# HAXM is not compatible with windows

Tags: android

Why is the intel x86 emulator accelerator (HAXM installer) is showing not compatible with windows. I have windows 10 ,64 bit.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm5tE.png)
i enabled virtualization and my processor support it ,(cor i7 3632qm)

Comment: Windows version?

Comment: @alan veriosn 1709

Comment: @Alan befor it version , i had version 1803 , and i had this problem too